# I am not booting to the gnome desktop since upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, 16.04, gnome-terminal

I have just finished a rather long problem on my dual-boot Ubuntu PC.  During that issue I upgraded to 16.04.  I am now getting the graphic login and during the login I got, briefly, the information bar at the top.  However, after completely booting I have my background and the only interaction I can have is if I right click the mouse and choose "Open Terminal".
I have changed the grub line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="init=/lib/systemd/systemd"

I am new to the systemd is there further initialization I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Start in text-only mode

- Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, which will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> and your machine will begin the boot process.
- After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> with this option highlighted.
- The PC will start in a terminal.

### Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install `aptitude` and `deborphan`

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of `ubuntu and unity` that are not necessary in gnome

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(gnome))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(gnome))))'
```

Reinstall `gnome-desktop`

```
apt-get install --reinstall gnome
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```